# look for a solution to develop the mutex

Tags: java, multithreading, dictionary, synchronization, mutex

I am looking for a solution for the following problem:

I am designing a java class that contain a map, which is being manipulated by multiple threads. Those threads will have operations include:

1. iterate : there will be a thread iterating the map, while iterating, it will read and update the values of some entries
2. put : one of the thread will add entries to the map
3. get : one or more thread will read the map periodically

The challenging part is， I can't put the mutex on all 3 methods, because iterate will call get and put, which will cause a dead lock.

Please advise how could I design the class and mutex to make it work.

Thanks

Comment: If you don't have to use mutex (for homework), you would be better off using a class from java.util.concurrent, such as ConcurrentHashMap, which deals correctly with iterators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mutex that's acquired when you use the `synchronized` keyword are reentrant, so if iterate already owns the mutex, then it can reacquire the same when calling get and put.

That said, I'd create your map member field as a `ConcurrentHashMap`. Then, your `iterate` won't have `ConcurrentModificationException` problems (for more details, see the javadocs of the `ConcurrentHashMap` class). Similarly locking for both `get` and `put` will be handled for you by `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Answer (score 1):

There are more ways to skin a cat, the classic one being to use unprotected private get/put methods from iterate, the public get/set methods wrap that in a mutex lock